# LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers() doesn't update loggers archive life time

Tags: c#, xml, logging, nlog

Nlog.config

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="DEBUG" internalLogFile="temp\nlog-internal.log">

  
  <variable name="LogLevel" value="DEBUG"/>
  <variable name="brief" value="${longdate} | ${level} | ${logger} | ${message}"/>
  <variable name="verbose" value="${longdate} | ${machinename} | ${processid} | ${processname} | ${level} | ${logger} | ${message}"/>
  <variable name="logLifetime"  value="3"/>

  
  
  <targets >
    <target name="Global" xsi:type="File" fileName="Logs/GlobalLog.txt"  archiveNumbering="Date" enableArchiveFileCompression="true" archiveFileName="Archive/IPSlog.{#}.zip" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" 
     maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime}"
    archiveEvery="Day" />
    <target name="S42K" xsi:type="File" layout="${brief}" fileName="Logs/S42K.txt" archiveNumbering="Date" enableArchiveFileCompression="true" archiveFileName="Archive/S42K.{#}.zip" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
    maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime}"
    archiveEvery="Day" />
    <target name="ServerApp"  xsi:type="File" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" archiveNumbering="Date" enableArchiveFileCompression="true" archiveFileName="Archive/IPSlog.{#}.zip" fileName="Logs/ServerApp.txt" 
     maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime}"
    archiveEvery="Day" />
    <target name="Color" xsi:type="ColoredConsole"  />

      <target name="S42KRawData" xsi:type="File" layout="${brief}" fileName="Logs/S42KRawData.txt" archiveNumbering="Date" enableArchiveFileCompression="true" archiveFileName="Archive/S42KRawData.{#}.zip" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
   maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime}"
   archiveEvery="Day" />
      <target name="Advancis" xsi:type="File" layout="${brief}" fileName="Logs/Advancis.txt" archiveNumbering="Date" enableArchiveFileCompression="true" archiveFileName="Archive/Advancis.{#}.zip" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
  maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime}"
  archiveEvery="Day" />
      
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="Global" minlevel="${LogLevel}"  writeTo="Global,Color" />
    <logger name="S42K" minlevel="${LogLevel}" writeTo="S42K,Color" />
    <logger name="ServerApp" minlevel="${LogLevel}" writeTo="ServerApp,Color" ></logger>
    <logger name="S42KRawData" minlevel="TRACE" writeTo="S42KRawData,Color" />
    <logger name="Advancis" minlevel="${LogLevel}" writeTo="Advancis,Color" />
    
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

code part when service started

```
 LogManager.Configuration.Variables["logLifetime"] = SetingFromINIfile.Setting[settingIterator++].Parameter;//contains "1"
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

**but loggers doesn't reconfig and use 3 days by default**

Some details:

- ReconfigExistingLoggers() invoked in a task
- LogManager.Configuration.Variables["logLifetime"] return 1 after changing

[image: archives()]

what is the problem?

Comment: Each log file contains a date so each day you get a new filename.  So what are you updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog [Config Variables](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables) can operate in two modes:

- Static mode - `${logLifetime}`
- Dynamic mode - `${var:logLifetime}`

Static mode works for all types of properties independent of their type, but they will not react to runtime changes.

Dynamic mode only works for properties of the type NLog Layout. [MaxArchiveDays is integer type](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/P_NLog_Targets_FileTarget_MaxArchiveDays.htm) and will not work. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer

As a work around you can update the NLog Configuration from code, and assign the property directly on the FileTarget-objects:

```
var fileTargets = LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.OfType<FileTarget>();
```

Another work-around would be to use `autoReload="true"` and just update the NLog.config file and NLog will [automatically reload](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#automatic-reconfiguration) the configuration.